# Counting contiguous numbers within a list

Tags: python-3.x, random, contiguous

I am completely new to the topic of programming but interested. 
I am coding in python 3.x and have a question to my latest topic:

We have a list, containing a few tenthousands of randomly generated integers between 1 and 7.

```
import random

list_of_states = []
n = int(input('Enter number of elements:'))

for i in range(n):
    list_of_states.append(random.randint(1,7))

print (list_of_states)
```

Afterwards, I would like to count the contiguous numbers in this list and put them into an numpy.array

```
example: [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 7, 3, 1, 1, 1]

1    1
2    1
3    1
4    3
7    1
3    1
1    3
```

I would like to know whether someone has a hint/an idea of how I could do this.
This part is a smaller part of a markov chain wherefor I need the frequency of each number.

Thanks for sharing
Nadim

Answer (score 0):

Below is a crude way of doing this. I am creating a list of lists and then converting it to a numpy array. Please use this only a guidance and improvise on this.

```
import numpy as np

num_list = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,1,1,1,1,3,3,3]

temp_dict = {}

two_dim_list = []

for x in num_list:
    if x in temp_dict:
        temp_dict[x] += 1
    else:
        if temp_dict:
            for k,v in temp_dict.items():
                two_dim_list.append([k,v])
            temp_dict = {}
        temp_dict[x] = 1

for k,v in temp_dict.items():
    two_dim_list.append([k,v])

print ("List of List = %s" %(two_dim_list))

two_dim_arr = np.array(two_dim_list)

print ("2D Array = %s" %(two_dim_arr))
```

Output:

```
List of List = [[1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1], [6, 4], [7, 4], [1, 4], [3, 3]]
2D Array = [[1 4]
 [2 3]
 [3 1]
 [4 1]
 [5 1]
 [6 4]
 [7 4]
 [1 4]
 [3 3]]
```